# Git: display the contents of a file through all branches

Tags: git, branch

`git log --all` is very convenient when I work with a large software project with many diverted branches.

Suppose I found a bug in one of the branches, and would like to check if other branches should also be corrected or not.  Are there any better ways than repeated `git checkout` over all branches, or the below trick based on `git cat-file` (not really handy) ?

```
for b in `git branch -r`; do echo $b; git cat-file -p ${b}:path/to/my.file; done
```

Comment: Rather than `for b in \`git branch -r\``, consider using `git for-each-ref`.

Comment: Do you have a way of programmatically check whether the bug is present, rather than dump the whole file to stdout?

Comment: @Jubobs Unfortunately that is not possible for my intended use case.